# Show many products from a category from many-to-many relationship in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

So I’m making a catalogue using Laravel 7.* and I have a problem.

I have many products and many categories. I have created a many-to-many relationship so a product can be in many categories.

Now, what I am trying to do is to show in a page each category with related products, but obviously I am doing something wrong.

Below you may see some code:

**Product.php:**

```
public function categories()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

**Category.php:**

```
public function product()
{
return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

**Show.blade.php**

```
@php
$products = \App\Product::with('categories')->find(1);
@endphp
@foreach ($products as $id)
{{ $id->name }}<br>
@endforeach
```

**Any help please?**

Comment: find(1) will return the single product with id 1, not a list of products, what is the result you are trying to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

I fetched categories in controller and send to view. Then for each category displayed each product.

Answer (score 0):

Get all the categories and show products related to them.

```
@php
$categories= \App\Category::all();
@endphp
@foreach($categories as $category)
   
           @foreach($category->product as $product)
                   {{$product->name}}
           @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You need also Id of category that you want to show products related to it.

According To [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73912941/4363970)
Try this:

```
$category_id = 1; // Desired Category Id

$products = \App\Product::whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($category_id) {

   $query->where('category_id', $category_id);

})->paginate();
```

I also added pagination.