# How to create a filter by category in MANY TO MANY relationship in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a many to many between Article and Category model and a pivot containing category_id and article_id records. At the click on the category link I would have a page that shows me all articles related to the category clicked but i can't create the right function in the controller.

```
public function showcategory($id){
    $articles=Article::whereHas('categories',function($query){
         $query->whereIn('category_id', $id);
    })->get();

    return view('categorydetail',compact('articles);
}
```

Comment: Can you please include the correlating route definition for this code. In general the code seems fine, what are you experiencing as an error?

Comment: hi mrhn i resolved with this controller public function showcategory($id)
    {
        $categories = Category::find($id);
        $selectedArticles = $categories->articles()->get();
        return view('categorydetail', compact('selectedArticles', 'categories'));
    }

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems not fine. Eloquent `whereIn` is expecting an array as second parameter. Use `where` instead.

```
$articles=Article::whereHas('categories',function($query){
     $query->where('category_id', $id);
})->get();
```

Ideally, this is not the best practice. You'd better try the flow below:

```
//Category.php
public function articles() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Article::class);
}
//Controller
    $category = Category::with('articles')->find($id);
    if (empty($category)) {
        //show 404 error or redirection
    }
    $articles = $category->articles()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, you just need to pass the id variable

The variable is passed using the code by adding the following code **use($id)**
You should use where instead of whereIn

```
public function showcategory($id){
     $articles=Article::whereHas('categories',function($query) use($id){
          $query->where('category_id', $id);
     })->get();
    
     return view('categorydetail',compact('articles));
}
```

There is also another way

```
public function showcategory($id){
     $category= Category::find($id);
     empty($category) ? abort(404) : '';
     $articles = $category->articles()->paginate(10);
     return view('categorydetail',compact('articles));
}
```